# How to debug python script in C level using GDB. Give me a simple example for this

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging, gdb, gdb-python

How to debug python script in C level using GDB. Give me a simple example for this.My primary goal is to get the trace of libc function called from my python script.

Comment: Please say you're using `ctypes` or trying to do a low-level hack... And that you've got the debug version of Python.

Comment: Yes, I am using python-devel version. Also I want to do a low-level hack

Comment: Oh, good. You get an up vote then. Any particular reason you've picked Python 2 for your hack?

Comment: I need to go for both python 2 and 3.. starting from python 2 for now

Comment: You can follow instructions on https://wiki.python.org/moin/DebuggingWithGdb to debug python script. To get the trace of libc function you can set a breakpoint on it with `b <libc function name>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the thing is for binary(.so) files, you surely cannot apply breakpoint to a particular line, but surely you can apply breakpoint to a function.
Say using

```
(gdb) b func_name
```

you can easily apply breakpoint to a function and thereby obtain the backtrace whenever the breakpoint is found.
First run your python sc

1. Start gdb:

   ```
   gdb -ex r --args python demo.py
   ```
2. Apply breakpoint:

   ```
   (gdb) b func_name
   ```
3. Run:

   ```
   (gdb) run
   ```

This should work for your case.

Comment: So where would this look for function "func_name". I need to know this. This would play a crucial role in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You can always Python using gdb and set breakpoints as you like

```
gdb -ex r --args python script.py args
```

If you want to look what happens in Python while running Python script I suggest to use mixed mode

```
gdb -ex r --args python -m pdb script.py
```

This way, you can break in pdb, then press `Ctrl-C` and end up inside gdb. Then, `bt` will give you stack trace inside Python.

Comment: So where to add breakpoints in such a case? say for a c file abc.c, I add "b abc.c:10"... but for the python file, I cannot add the breakpoint directly to python as far as my understanding goes. The c files used here would be the binary(.so) files... how to add breakpoint to them now?

Comment: You also need:  python-debuginfo package